# How to get an asp control id from c# code?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a asp control button that when I look at it in IE 9 developers tool I see it's id is
`ctl00_m_g_0e632166_55b3_4470_971c_bd562d4904c8_ctl00_Button2`.

Is there a way I can access this id in the c# code?
Something like `Button2.getID`?

Curently I am inserting javascript code that will need to find this control to do various things and the method I am using isn't good, it's basically checking if the suffix of all input id's is `Button2`. I want to find a better way...

Thanks

Comment: at what point are you wanting to get the ID you could try something like 

 var btnId = Request.Form[Button2.UniqueID];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Button2.ClientID` is what you're looking for i think.

docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

You can also control how this is set by setting the [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx#Y0) should get you the DOM element ID.

Answer (score 2):

If your control is not in a repater or grid, and it is unique to the page, you can set `ClientIDMode="Static"` and it will be whatever ID you give it. Otherwise, you will have to use `ClientID` as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

alert($("#<%= Button2.ClientID %>").click());